# pylab.scatter plotting a different graph than excel on same data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data using pylab scatter function. I'm using

```
pylab.scatter(X, Y)
pylab.show()
```

X and Y are python lists where each element is << int >> datatype. When I plot the graph using the above, I get a straight line graph. However, when I use excel to plot the same data, it is a long tailed graph. The correct distribution is the long tail. Why am I then getting a straight line when using pylab?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about how you're using excel to plot the data.  Excel has many types of plots.  You should also give an example of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apology! The issue was not related to pylab.

The problem was that I had initialized X and Y as -

```
X = Y = list()
```

Due to this, whatever values I inserted in list Y, it became same as X. And hence the straight line.